# How to upgrade spring-hateoas when using spring boot?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I was reading about spring-hateoas and it appears there are a lot of changes with 1.0. I want to switch to 1.0

However my pom.xml is pulling in 0.25.2.

I tried using

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

it still pulls in 0.25.2. If I explicitly put in

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

it pulls in 1.0 but I get runtime error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.hateoas.RelProvider
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
```

How do I use spring boot and also spring-hateoas 1.0?

pom

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- the core, which includes Streaming API, shared low-level abstractions (but NOT data-binding) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Just the annotations; use this dependency if you want to attach annotations
             to classes without connecting them to the code. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- databinding; ObjectMapper, JsonNode and related classes are here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
            <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you post your complete pom.xml?

Comment: from the exception it looks like springfox is using 0.25?

Comment: Struggling with this problem for a week now. It would be really nice someone shed a light on this.

Comment: Just a comment. For people using `Spring Boot 2.3.x` + `Spring Cloud Hoxton` + `springdoc-openapi`, my full resolved dependencies: https://gist.github.com/rekhubs/9a635927458cd5a1f243ed0536296673

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this problem today! The solution I found was to define the version of hateoas as a new property in pom. That way you can override the version of hateoas provided by the parent spring boot parent project.

````xml
<properties>
        <...other project related version goes here as usual ..>
        <spring-hateoas.version>1.0.1.RELEASE</spring-hateoas.version>
</properties>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the HATEOAS upgrade from `0.×.×.RELEASE` to `1.×.×.RELEASE`, I followed the guidelines here, since some refactoring was needed:
https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/05/spring-hateoas-1-0-m1-released

I used the `migrate-to-1.0.sh` script ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/etc/migrate-to-1.0.sh)) provided by Spring HATEOAS, and generally I made the following changes on our POJOs:

- `ResourceSupport` is now `RepresentationModel`
- `Resource<T>` is now `EntityModel<T>`
- `Resources<T>` is now `CollectionModel<T>`
- `PagedResources<T>` is now `PagedModel<T>`
- `ControllerLinkBuilder` is now `WebMvcLinkBuilder`
- `Identifiable<T>` interface is removed and not necessary anymore
- `Link.REL_SELF` is now `IanaLinkRelations.SELF_VALUE`, and so on